# Возможно ли узнать когда динамическое изображение загрузилось? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть код что динамически меняет src изображения на странице, типа

```
var myUrl = 'http://google.com/logo.jpg';
$('.img').attr('src', myUrl);
```

Как можно узнать когда это изображение загрузилось и отрендерилось в бразере?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Спасибо, работает